# Confusion regarding PID library?

Tags: library, pid

PID library is available(built in) in standard installation  of arduino IDE or do we have to download it additionaly after installing our IDE?

How can i check which of libraries are available in my standard installation?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Library Manager and search for the library you want. You will
see a list of libraries matching your query. Under the name of each of
those libraries, you will see a line showing the author and the version
number.

- if this lines stats with “Built-in”, then it is a library that comes
  with the standard installation of the IDE
- if the line ends with “INSTALLED”, then this library is installed in
  your system.

Comment: Can you please name any famoous/common library which is "installed" and also any "library" that is built in?